# Function that removes a row from the table is not working after adding jQuery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#delrow').click(function(){
                    alert(':)');
                    $(this).closest('tr').animate({'backgroundColor':'#EF3E23','color':'#fff'},300,function(){
                        $(this).remove();
                    });
                    return false;
                });
            });
        </script>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
    Hello
        <table>
            <tr>
            <td>abc</td>
            <td><a id="delrow" title="Click to remove" href="#">Delete</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Here you can test my code: http://goo.gl/XNQb5j

The "Delete" button should remove the row from the table.
It's working when I don't include jQuery UI (but then, of course, animation is not working).
What am I doing wrong?

Sorry for my English errors.

Comment: The animation is the key. It's not working properly preventing the callback (on animation end) to be fired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the version of the jQuery UI that youve linked is incompatible with the version of the jQuery you linked. better take the version numbers from jQuery examples on their website.

notice how your code works when the versions are compatible:

```html
<HTML>

<HEAD>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.2.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#delrow').click(function() {
        alert(':)');
        $(this).closest('tr').animate({
          'backgroundColor': '#EF3E23',
          'color': '#fff'
        }, 300, function() {
          $(this).remove();
        });
        return false;
      });
    });
  </script>
</HEAD>

<BODY>Hello
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td><a id="delrow" title="Click to remove" href="#">Delete</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</BODY>

</HTML>
```